# unable to get Textarea value using jquery

Tags: jquery, textarea

```
<textarea id="txtDescription" class="smalltextarea" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

var getText= $("#txtDescription").val();
alert(getText);
});
});
```

when i type some text on textarea and press submit button my script return
[object HTML TextAreaElement]
not the textarea text or value;

```
$("#txtDescription").val();
$("#txtDescription").text();
$("#txtDescription").html();
```

same output [object HTML TextAreaElement]

Comment: Hellow @Jitender : Did you use any 3rd party plugin like tiny mce or anything other ?

Comment: It works just fine with $().val() - http://jsfiddle.net/Hipnozy/St6wR/

Comment: Where exactly the jQuery part is declared?

Comment: @Jitender : I seem to execute your exactly code from my side and it work well so please check if their were any conflict by ids or their were and 3d party software behind this problem :)

Comment: @jitender : you don't reply on my comment or even on my answer did your problem is solved ?

Comment: I am very sorry sir, your code and my code is same. i don't know what is going on... thank you for your post sir

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not with the code you've shown. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VkcF/1/) with the exact same code. My guess is that you could have a conflict with the id: check if there's only one element named `btnSubmit` and `txtDescription`

Comment: Well then the problem comes from somewhere else you need to isolate it. The code as you have it works.

Comment: may be you are right. I know that my code is correct. but the thing i am able to get all textboxs and span val on my page even dropdown val. but not the textarea  val

Answer (score 0):

use first one `$("#txtDescription").val();` 
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhu5013/a3A6y/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var text = $('textarea#txtDescription').val();
```

Comment: I am not able to understand that problem. every thing working fine. i have using 3 textboxs and 1 textarea. i am able to get texbox val but not able to get texarea value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try giving your variable a value as following and tell me the result :

```
var getText = document.getElementById("txtDescription").value;
```

Comment: @Jitender : If this doesn't work so may you please post your complete code here as i think that you may have missing some in somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you had written a short version of your textarea tag, but I maybe have a situation. If it's the solution that's perfect, or it will maybe help people like me who google that problem and are directed here.

I am working in asp.net and just by erasing the

> runat="server"

attribute of your textarea tag makes working the

> $('#myTextarea').val();

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery("#txtDescription").val();
jQuery("#txtDescription").text();
jQuery("#txtDescription").html();
```